# Filter nodes by currently logged-in user

Tags: 7, views

I want a view which shows nodes authored by the currently logged-in user. I can't figure out how to do this in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out. Had to add a contextual filter of "Content: User posted or commented" with the default value of "user ID from logged in user".

Comment: I know this is old but Google brought me here. Be carefull with this one, since adding an arbitrary user ID to the url allows you to load the list for another user. This should not be used for security reasons!
Take a look at this alternative solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420031/drupal-7-views-3-usercurrent-filter-is-missing

Answer (score 4):

just add a view for all your nodes. Then add a "relationship" for "Content: Author".
Now add a "contextual filter" for the field "user: uid" with a default argument for "userid of logged in user" to filter the view.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should be the same as in Drupal 6.  Add a filter of `User: Current` to the view

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Content:Author relationship or contextual filter didn't work in for me because it joins the node's author field to the user table.  In my case I created a field called "active" and I only wanted to display it on a view if it was active or if the current user's role is admin or custom admin.

The Current user has roles filter provided by the [Views Published or Roles](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_published_or_roles) module solved this issue for me.